# Android app getting error send image using Smack and Openfire 4.1.4

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, file-transfer

I'm developing chat app using `XMPP` with Openfire 4.1.4, One to one text chat working fine, but while I send image getting error

Here is my code for file send:

```
Log.e("ad",">selectedImagePath====="+selectedImagePath);
    FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(Config.conn1);
                OutgoingFileTransfer transfer;
                transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(userJid+"/"+Config.conn1); //JID - user@host/resource
                File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
                try {
                    transfer.sendFile(file, "image message test");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                    if (transfer.getStatus().equals(AMPExtension.Status.error)) {
                        Log.e("ad","ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
                    } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                        Log.e("ad","Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) ) {    
                    Log.e("ad","refused cancelled error" + transfer.getError());
                }
                else  if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error))
                {
                    Log.e("ad","error="+ transfer.getError());
                }
                else  if  (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled))
                {
                    Log.e("ad","cancelled");
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("ad","Success");
                }
```

Here is my log:

```
  02-23 14:56:32.489 14951-14951/com.app.chatv1 E/ad: >selectedImagePath=====/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1519194363122.jpg
02-23 14:56:33.490 14951-14951/com.app.chatv1 E/ad: error=null
```

I have another related question: when I sent image to server successfully  where it will place at server location?